# How to save input from python to XML

Tags: python, xml

Is there a way for me to save something that I have inputted in the variable in python, to save it to XML. For example:

```
def UserInput():
    select = TextCheck('Gas','Oil')
    money = NumberCheck('How much did you pay: ')
    gas_station = str(input('On what gas station were you: '))
    datum = DateCheck('Input date: ')
    liters = NumberCheck('How many liters did you fill: ')
```

How can I save that input in XML?(and i translated the program from my language to english so sorry if i typed something stupid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and probably fastest way to do this would be simply to write the output to file like so:

```
some_number = int(input('input a number: '))
f = open('number.xml', 'r+')
f.write('<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n<number>{}</number>'.format(some_number))
```

Of course, if you're getting into more complex XML, you'll probably want to use something like the ElementTree API

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
some_number = int(input('input a number: '))
el = et.Element("number").text = some_number
tree = et.ElementTree(el)
tree.write("number.xml")
```

Comment: That is really helpful, alnd what if i have a function with those variables and i just need to save the input from the variables from those functions

Comment: Question: I lean towards the ElementTree solution even for simple XML, because I thought it took care of escaping, etc. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: That sounds fine.  You'll experience very a minor performance hit, but that shouldn't affect you unless you're doing millions of operations per day (in which case, you should be using a DB vs FS for persistence, anyway). Good luck!

Comment: @StevenMoseley sorry to bother you but can you check it out now because i did the same thing and nothing, i am really sorry if  i'm a drag but i'm a newbie programmer so yeah :D